Docker and npm installations failing with "bad record MAC" error due to slow network on mobile hotspot
I've been encountering a persistent issue while working with Docker and npm installations on my system. Whenever I try to run docker build . -t <image_name> or npm install, I consistently receive the following error:
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2559)

After extensively researching the problem, I've found that this error is typically attributed to network issues, particularly slow internet connections. However, I'm puzzled because my internet connection, particularly when using my mobile hotspot, seems to be fast and stable for all other tasks including downloading large files and browsing.
I've attempted various troubleshooting steps including:
Changing network environments (different Wi-Fi networks, mobile hotspot).
Updating Intel Wi-Fi drivers.
Verifying that other network-related tasks such as curling Debian ISOs work flawlessly both in Windows/PowerShell and in WSL2/Ubuntu/bash.
Exploring potential router or driver issues.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists, and I'm unable to proceed with my work effectively.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any insights into what might be causing this issue? Any suggestions for further troubleshooting or potential solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Connected with a different network(WIFI) and all docker pull npm install works properly there.
Changed my intel wifi drivers, still probelm is there

